# I tried to show up the image file to gui program using JFrame in java

Tags: java, image, user-interface, jframe

I am a new java learner :>

I want to display the image to GUI program using JFrame in java.
But the image is not showed up..

---

DynamicBeat.java

```java
package dynamic_beat_2;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DynamicBeat extends JFrame{
    
    private Image screenImage;
    private Graphics screenGraphic;
    
    private Image introBackground;
    
    public DynamicBeat() {
        setTitle("Dynamic Beat");
        setSize(Main.SCREEN_WIDTH, Main.SCREEN_HEIGHT); 
        setResizable(false); 
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        
        setVisible(true);   
        
        introBackground = new ImageIcon("../images/introBackground.jpg").getImage();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        screenImage = createImage(Main.SCREEN_WIDTH, Main.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        screenGraphic = screenImage.getGraphics();
        screenDraw(screenGraphic);
        g.drawImage(screenImage, 0, 0, null);
    
    public void screenDraw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(introBackground, 0, 0, null);
        this.repaint();
```

---

Main.java

```java
package dynamic_beat_2;

public class Main {

    public static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1280;
    public static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 720;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DynamicBeat();
    }

}
```

---

dynamic_beat2 => C:\Tech\project\DynamicBeat\src\dynamic_beat_2

introBackground => C:\Tech\project\DynamicBeat\src\images\introBackground.jpg

---

1. I tried changing 'paint()' to 'paintComponent()'.
2. I tried changing form of the resource

- ("../images/introBackground.jpg")
- ("/images/introBackground.jpg")
- ("introBackground.jpg")
- ...

3. It was my code before changing to present code as above.

```java
introBackground = new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("../images/introBackground.jpg")).getImage();
    }
```

but I got the error from this code.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()"
```

4. Eclipes (Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0))

Java (Version: 17.0.6)

Comment: Since the image is in the src directory, it’s likely embedded, so you’ll need to use Class#getResource to get a reference to and you should probably use ImageIO.read to load the image

Comment: Good advice from @MadProgrammer. Use `introBackground = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/introBackground.jpg")).getImage();` and get rid of `screenDraw` - it's likely to cause infinite recursion.